# Parent Span Not Connecting in OpenTelemetry with Kafka and Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, trace, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm working with two Java services connected via Kafka, and I've integrated OpenTelemetry for distributed tracing. In Service A, I create a parent span, and in the Kafka message, I include two string values: traceId and spanId.

However, in Service B, I'm having trouble using these values to connect a new span to the parent span.

Here's what I've tried in Service B:

```
SpanContext spanContext = SpanContext.create(parentTraceId, parentSpanId, TraceFlags.getDefault(), TraceState.getDefault());

Span kafkaMessageSpan = otelTracer.spanBuilder("kafka-message2-processing")
        .setParent(Context.current().with(Span.wrap(spanContext)))
        .startSpan();

kafkaMessageSpan.end();
```

The parentTraceId and parentSpanId values look like this in the logs:

parentTraceId: 5e3a44aa9817427c970800316ff717e7
parentSpanId: 91367512fa425dca

What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

I've also tried to use createFromRemoteParent. but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do this? If you instrument your services with OpenTelemetry, it will do the magic.

OpenTelemetry propagates the parent context from producer in message headers and consumer use that context and build a child span and update the tracing.
Even if you want to disable and enable the propagation, there is a configuration for that.

```
otel.instrumentation.kafka.client-propagation.enabled = true # default
```

Refer following tickets:

[ticket1](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/1113).
[ticket2](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues/3615)

check code [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/instrumentation/kafka/kafka-clients/kafka-clients-0.11/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/kafkaclients/v0_11/KafkaSingletons.java#L22)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm working on projects using Kafka Streams and Scala Streams. I've been trying to find a straightforward way to perform the injection, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. The Injection I tried to do manually in post, shouldn't work?